# Ver Miniaturas (thumbnail) con la API de Google Drive

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, google-drive

¿Cómo puedo ver las miniaturas (thumbnail) de mis imágenes de *google Drive*?

Es decir: que la api de *google drive* me devuelva la url del thumbnail.
También uso `jquery`, si es necesario o para facilitarlo.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      // Your Client ID can be retrieved from your project in the Google
      // Developer Console, https://console.developers.google.com
      var CLIENT_ID = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com';

      var SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly'];

      /**
       * Check if current user has authorized this application.
       */
      function checkAuth() {
        gapi.auth.authorize(
          {
            'client_id': CLIENT_ID,
            'scope': SCOPES.join(' '),
            'immediate': true
          }, handleAuthResult);
      }

      /**
       * Handle response from authorization server.
       *
       * @param {Object} authResult Authorization result.
       */
      function handleAuthResult(authResult) {
        var authorizeDiv = document.getElementById('authorize-div');
        if (authResult && !authResult.error) {
          // Hide auth UI, then load client library.
          authorizeDiv.style.display = 'none';
          loadDriveApi();
        } else {
          // Show auth UI, allowing the user to initiate authorization by
          // clicking authorize button.
          authorizeDiv.style.display = 'inline';
        }
      }

      /**
       * Initiate auth flow in response to user clicking authorize button.
       *
       * @param {Event} event Button click event.
       */
      function handleAuthClick(event) {
        gapi.auth.authorize(
          {client_id: CLIENT_ID, scope: SCOPES, immediate: false},
          handleAuthResult);
        return false;
      }

      /**
       * Load Drive API client library.
       */
      function loadDriveApi() {
        gapi.client.load('drive', 'v2', listFiles);
      }

      /**
       * Print files.
       */
      function listFiles() {
        var request = gapi.client.drive.files.list({
            'maxResults': 10
          });

          request.execute(function(resp) {
            appendPre('Files:');
            var files = resp.items;
            if (files && files.length > 0) {
              for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                var file = files[i];
                appendPre(file.title + ' (' + file.id + ')');
              }
            } else {
              appendPre('No files found.');
            }
          });
      }

      /**
       * Append a pre element to the body containing the given message
       * as its text node.
       *
       * @param {string} message Text to be placed in pre element.
       */
      function appendPre(message) {
        var pre = document.getElementById('output');
        var textContent = document.createTextNode(message + '\n');
        pre.appendChild(textContent);

      }

    </script>
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=checkAuth">
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="authorize-div" style="display: none">
      <span>Authorize access to Drive API</span>
      <!--Button for the user to click to initiate auth sequence -->
      <button id="authorize-button" onclick="handleAuthClick(event)">
        Authorize
      </button>
    </div>
    <pre id="output"></pre>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Según la [documentación](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files), parece que debería haber disponible algunas opciones para obtener el *thumbnail* de un fichero en Google Drive:

1. [`thumbnailLink`](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files#thumbnailLink): una cadena de texto con un enlace temporal (sólo dura unas pocas horas) al *thumbnail* del fichero.
2. [`thumbnail.image`](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files#thumbnail.image): los bytes del *thumbnail* del fichero codificado en Base-64 (conforme a la sección 5 del [RFC 4648](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4648.txt))

...pero, o bien hay algún tipo de bug, o bien yo no las he sabido utilizar (bastante más posible), porque parece que no me funcionan del todo y siempre me devuelven `undefined`.

Si no consigues que los métodos de arriba te funcionen, podrías utilizar una alternativa simple: utilizar la URL que Google Drive utiliza para mostrar los *thumbnails*: https://drive.google.com/thumbnail?id=ID_DEL_FICHERO.

Así, por ejemplo, en el código de arriba para obtener la URL del *thumbnail* podrías hacer algo como esto:

```
request.execute(function(resp) {
    appendPre('Files:');
    var files = resp.items;
    if (files && files.length > 0) {
        for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            var file = files[i];
            appendPre(file.title + ' (' + file.id + ')');


            // Código para el thumbnail
            var thumbnail = "https://drive.google.com/thumbnail?id=" + file.id;
            appendPre("THUMBNAIL = " + thumbnail);
        }
    } else {
        appendPre('No files found.');
    }
});
```